# Spring restful webservice returning JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I just took the tutorial over at Spring.io http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and created a simple rest service. But, does anybody know how I can return multiple objects in JSON format? If I for instance have a person class with a name and an id, how can I add three persons to /persons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `@ResponseBody` annotation and just return whatever you want, providing that those objects can be jsonized.

For example, you can have a bean like this:

```
@Data
public class SomePojo {
   private String someProp;
   private List<String> someListOfProps;
}
```

and then in your controller you can have:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/someRequestMapping")
public List<SomePojo> getSomePojos(){
  return Arrays.<String>asList(new SomePojo("someProp", Arrays.<String>asList("prop1", "prop2"));
}
```

and Spring by default would use its Jackson mapper to do it, so you'd get a response like:

```
[{"someProp":"someProp", "someListOfProps": ["prop1", "prop2"]}]
```

The same way, you can bind to some objects, but this time, using the `@RequestBody` annotation, where jackson would be used this time to pre-convert the json for you.

what you can do is

```
@RequestMapping("/someOtherRequestMapping")
public void doStuff(@RequestBody List<SomePojo> somePojos) {
   //do stuff with the pojos
}
```

Comment: Pretty cool!
It worked =)
Im very new to Spring and the whole Rest idea.

Do you know any good tutorials on this? 
I need to get a json which looks something like this:

[
 {"id": 0, "name":"Sancho Panza"},
 {"id": 1, "name":"Man Mansen"},
 {"id": 2, "name":"Heman matt"}
]

Comment: Then make a list of those guys and return it :)

Comment: Hehe, yeah. I was a bit unsure, because when I tried it didnt work. But now it does. Small syntax error. Thank youu! Works like a charm :D

Answer (score 1):

Try returning a list from the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/greetings")
public @ResponseBody List<Greeting> greetings(
        @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    return Arrays.asList(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),String.format(template, name)));
}
```